# Prettier add a semicolon before [myVariable]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, prettier

I don't know why but prettier add me a semicolon before my variable in my code like this.

```
if (!article && app.$config.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  [article] = await app.$contentful.getEntries({
    content_type: 'content',
    'fields.route': params.id,
    options: { levels: 3 },
  })
}
```

Will be transform to :

```
if (!article && app.$config.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  ;[article] = await app.$contentful.getEntries({
    content_type: 'content',
    'fields.route': params.id,
    options: { levels: 3 },
  })
}
```

The error look like that :

[image: Error prettier]

Comment: That's what it's _supposed_ to do. If you're not using semicolons to terminate lines, they're inserted where ASI would fail to put them (if you had something on the previous line, `[article]` would be an attempt to index into it). Read [the docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#semicolons) - _"It makes the line independent of other lines so you can move and add lines without having to think about ASI rules."_

Comment: When I try this [on prettier's playground](https://shorturl.at/beuHR), the `;` is not added. Please make sure you post something that is reproducible on their playground. You probably need extra context.

Comment: Yep, this is an edge case where you need a semicolon and ESlint is putting it here for you. Actually, you only need to know few cases where a semicolon is required and ditch it everywhere else. This is an example of required place.

Comment: @JuanMendes this is actually ESlint doing it's job, not Prettier. Of course, one can work through the other!

Comment: @kissu. The joys of trying to avoid semi-colons in JS. I don't like playing that game!

Comment: @kissu I don't understand your comment. I showed a link to the prettier playground. There is no need for a semi-colon there. It is very likely the problem is a previous statement that is making it required but we can't tell from the small snippet

Comment: The `;` is added when your code would behave in a non-intuitive manner. For example, if you have a declaration without a semi-colon preceding brackets or parentheses, which means JS would treat the brackets as property accessing and the parentheses as a function call . See [this simple example](https://shorturl.at/ejDNY)

Comment: @JuanMendes Oh ok it's clear now thank you ! And thank's all for your reply :)

Comment: @JuanMendes I meant that it was complaining because of a possible issue. You will actually get the warning even if there is no issue at all. You phrased it a bit better at the end and we do agree on the answer! I tend to omit semicolons myself and just remember the edge-cases. And ESlint is doing a great job on this one so that you don't even need to think about it.